# White space around background-image

Tags: css, background, background-image, whitespace, photoshop

There is white space appearing around the background image.

[image]

The code is as follow:

```
.class-of-div{

background: #00b5ff url(../img/cart.png) no-repeat;

background-position: 34px 4px;
}
```

This happens in all browsers

Comment: I assume that is not a CSS issue. Are you exporting it from photoshop? - @user1860754

Answer (score 5):

If you had kept a class to an image, than try this code:

```
.class-of-div {
    background: #00b5ff url(../img/cart.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 34px 4px;
    margin: -8px 0 0 -6px;
}
```

or simply use the below code:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

It's very simple than above.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use photoshop's "save for web" - use "save as" instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

Going by no imagery, set the width of the background image to 100%;

```
background-size:100%;
```

Comment: dosen't work, I have updated the link (http://instafynd.com/problem.PNG). Could you please check again

Answer (score 1):

add this to your css

```
*{padding:0px;
margin:0px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a graphic issue, photoshop "save for web" was actually creating that space (don't know why). But once I saved the file from "Save as". It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set display: inline-block; or display: block; to your image. If you can use css3, use `background-size: cover;` You can use `background-position: top left;` or likewise.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the problem, I created a fiddle to solve your problem. Please find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/bjJtA/)

I added a border around the div and set a height so that it is clear that there is no white space around the image.

```
.class-of-div{
    background: #00b5ff url('http://instafynd.com/problem.PNG') no-repeat 34px 4px;

    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid #f00;
}
```

Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a graphic issue, photoshop "save for web" was actually creating that space (don't know why). But once I saved the file from "Save as". It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in image. Download or create other. Is not CSS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. It was a graphic issue, photoshop "save for web" was actually creating that space (don't know why). But once I saved the file from "Save as". It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's the save for web option on photoshop and similar apps that causes this. I had the same problem using Adobe Illustrator Draw on the iPad. If the application you used for making the image doesn't have a "save as" option rather than "export for web" try using something like "preview" (mac) or paint on windows to crop it down.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for uping this topic, but in 2020 if you put this in html:

```
<img class="class_nbr_1">
```

and in your CSS:

```
.class_br_1 {
    background-image: url("../img/icons/image.png");
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
```

You'll have a white border, undisplayable. So juste use `<p>` instead of `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to solve the problem is to add the following css rule the class.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the image a background of the "container" (div) itself.
You don't have to use vertical-align, instead use:

```
body, html {
     margin: 0px;
     height: max-content;
}
```

Note: make sure you've already set the height and width of your container to 100%.

Hope this helped!

Comment: how this will remove white space around background-image, make a reproduce code.